# Use query Function inside blade without controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

How Can i use query function inside Blade without using controller
Something Like This::-

```php
Table::Select(Name)->get();
```

without using controller

Comment: why you want to use query in blade , it is not recommended by laravel ?

Comment: you should not use database queries inside your views.it will break mvc principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this -

```
@php
    $array = App\Table::Select(Name)->get();
@endphp
```

And then-

```
@foreach($array as $element)
    <p>{{ $element->name ?? '' }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it as below.

```
{{ $data = App\Table::Select('name')->get(); }}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Write this code in your Blade.php**

```
@php
    $array = App\Table::Select(Name)->get();
@endphp
```